# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a little misunderstanding here why do i have here an error  do i need to parse it what is wrong with this code  ?

```
UberTrackerEntities ctx = UberFactory.Context;
IEnumerable<HtUser> users = HtUser.GetAll();
string selectedBU = rcbBusinessUnits.SelectedValue;
string selectedDepartment = rcbDepartment.SelectedValue;

HtDepartment department = ctx.HtDepartments.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentId ==selectedDepartment);

if (department != null) 
{
    users = users.Where(u => u.HtDepartments.Contains(department));
}
```

Thanks for help and fast answer !

PS:I thing I'm just over thing it it seams just to be a stupid little error ...

Comment: The error here is pretty clear. One of `d.DepartmentId` and `selectedDepartment` is an `int`, and the other a `string`, and you can't compare the two with `==`.

Comment: you want  Microsoft people should include Which variable causing error. ? it's pretty informative. you can get the problematic code by looking it.

Comment: Give more details: what are you trying to do ? how are you doing it ? what was expected ? And what was the output which is different to your expectation ? without such info. no one can help you.

Comment: @lc. how can i do it correctly ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to convert `selectedDepartment` to integer before comparing it in the LINQ query.

```
int selectedDepartment = Convert.ToInt32(rcbDepartment.SelectedValue);
```

In your query:

```
ctx.HtDepartments.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentId == selectedDepartment);
```

`d.DepartmentId` is of type int whereas `selectedDepartment` is a string and you can compare both using `==` operator.

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. can you please edit your answer  ?

Comment: @MCraft, put a breakpoint on the line and see what you get inside `rcbDepartment.SelectedValue`, it must be something other than integer value

Comment: Get the value of the currently selected item in the combobox

Comment: @MCraft, what is the selected value

Answer (score 0):

`d.DepartmentId` is an `int` and `selectedDepartment` is a string.

You will need to convert using `Int32.Parse`, `Int32.TryParse` or `Convert.ToInt32`

Edit:

```
int selectedDepartmentId = Convert.ToInt32(selectedDepartment);

HtDepartment department = ctx.HtDepartments.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentId == selectedDepartmentId));
```

Comment: I have still a problem here LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @MCraft - Updated my answer.  Try that.

Comment: @MCraft - selectedDepartment must not be a valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

You selectedDepartment is of type string, and your id is of type int. You should convert your selectedDepartment to a int:

```
int selectedDepartment = Convert.ToInt32(rcbDepartment.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Then you should set the values of the rcbDepartment.SelectedValue to the keys of your departments. Eighter by hand or by databinding to the correct key.